# Get just list of attribute from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a very simple file from which I would like to extract the number values, only when the type is flower.

```
<myRoot>
    <header>
        ...
    </header>
    <body>
        ...
        <div type="animal" number="431">text1</div>
        <div type="flower" number="812">text2</div>
        <div type="flower" number="619">text3</div>
        ...
    </body>
</myRoot>
```

The exit I'm waiting for is :

```
812
619
```

My current xslt file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="//div">
        <xsl:value-of select="@type='flower'"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you use `xsl:output method="html"`, I would expect to see some HTML in the result you want, yet you have only shown plain text. As for selecting your attributes, use `//div[@type = 'flower']/@number` as the path, with an XSLT 2 or 3 processor you can simply use that path in `<xsl:value-of select="//div[@type = 'flower']/@number"/>`, with an XSLT 1 processor you will need to push the selected attributes through a template or pull them in through `xsl:for-each`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="div[@type='flower']">
   <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
</xsl:template>
```